# SPEED of LIGHT as photons reach black holes

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, photons, speed-of-light

As photons reach a black hole and begin fall in - is their speed increased as they go down (like a vacuum cleaner does to dust).

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24319/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98980/2451 , and links therein.

Comment: Also, photons travel at the speed of light, thus their speeds cannot increase.